# Naming a boost::thread with pthread_setname_np?

Tags: c++

I know there are no such thing as thread naming in boost.

However there is `pthread_setname_np` function which can be used on the native handle.

However, whatever guards I put around it, it always reports a build error:

[image]

Of course I have done this at the top of this file:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

Examining my `pthread.h` it indeed doesn't have this function defined.

GLIBC is at version 2.19, which should include this function.

Target is a standard Debian-Linux (ARM-based).

Why can't I use this function?

Comment: Have you defined `_GNU_SOURCE` before including `<pthread.h>`? According to [this page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html), it seems that you do need to define it in order to use this feature.

Comment: Yes, I have defined that too.